# Is it possible to upload sphinx pre-generated html documents into ReadTheDocs site?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-sphinx, pypi, read-the-docs

I'm having a python-3 project that uses the [plot-directive](http://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/extensions.html#inserting-matplotlib-plots), but this currently not supported by [ReadTheDocs](https://readthedocs.org).  Therefore i want to generate and upload the documents as i would normally do with the PyPi repository, but use the `-r` option to specify a different url.

I've tried the following, but it fails:

```
$ python3 setup.py build_sphinx register upload_docs -r https://readthedocs.org/pypi
running upload_docs
Using PyPI login from /home/user/.pypirc
Using upload directory /home/user/work/wltp.git/docs/_build/html
Submitting documentation to https://readthedocs.org/wltp/pypi
Upload failed (404): OK
```

I've also tried the following urls, but nothing worked:

- https://readthedocs.org/pypi/wltp
- https://readthedocs.org/pypi/wltp/latest
- https://readthedocs.org/wltp/pypi
- https://readthedocs.org/wltp/latest/pypi/

Is what i'm trying to achieve (in principle) possible?

Comment: This unresolved-yet RTD-issue for requesting this exact functionality has been scheduled for APIv2.1: https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1083

Comment: seems like that feature was dropped and still isn't supported. Too bad, I have the same problem due to the plot directive

Comment: I remember having (mis)used html_extra_path sphinx option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Issue should now be fixed according to [this issue](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/896#issuecomment-141005690).